# Why did the map (api v3) not change after dragging?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with my Google map app.
And  when  I developed it, I realized my app not working as I expected.

When I drag the cursor on map out of map's border, the map does not change to a new map.
It is as when you drag a static picture. It doesn't change.

Please someone help me.

**Update (code added):**

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);    
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map); 
    defaultSettings(); 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Well, without any code or any more information, my guess would be because you made a mistake in your code.

Comment: var map; 
      function initialize() { 
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center:  new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     defaultSettings();
      }     
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: When i drag out of the bound of the map, the map doesn't change as when you drag as picture to  another place and  move it to the old place when you have done.Zoom works properly.

Comment: Please provide a demo, this could'nt be answered by the given code.

Comment: i am working with Google map  v3 on window phone 7.

Comment: I used  the code that i have written on  window phone 7 browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Map will pan if you click to grab the map, drag the cursor to a new location *still within* the map, and then release the button. It does not pan if you start the drag inside the map, but then drag to a location outside the map.